# Capture One Wine Windows 10 Anniversary Update

Tags: 22.04, wine

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 trying to run Capture One through Wine 8.15. When running `wine <CaptureOne>`, I get a message saying that the Windows 10 Anniversary Update is required:

[image: Error Message]

How can I change the version of Windows to enable installation?

Comment: In WINE, the version of windows is set in the `winecfg` tool.  However, Win10 Anniversary Edition is not an option in Wine right now - you'll have to choose a Win11 compatibility which may introduce other problems.  This may also be one of those things you can't safely run in Wine.

Comment: Check with `https://www.winehq.org`. Not all Windows programs are available through `wine`. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a `wine` problem.

Comment: @ThomasWard Updating to windows 11 lets it install. There are still problems, but this question in particular is answered.

Comment: @MarkKocherovsky converted to an answer, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `winecfg` tool you can specify what Windows version to target in your WINE environment.

Windows 10 Anniversary Edition is not an option, but Windows 11 is.  Change it to that.

Make note that this may introduce other problems as well, and those may be issues beyond just Wine.  Check your app on the [WineHQ App DB](https://appdb.winehq.org) to make sure it works, because it might not work in WINE at all.